# How to add claims or roles

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims

How can I add claims after token validation? (i.e. in a controller)

In my app users authenticate with Azure B2C, but I want roles (or claim authorization) to be based on what a user selects after they log in...

I know I can add claims inside `OnTokenValidated`, but I want to do this after the user goes to a page and makes a selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible. The asp.net core authentication will generate the claim based on the token. If you add the claims in the controller but not update the token, that means the claim will not add into the token.

Next time, when the user login in, the claim is as same as the previous one. The token will not be modified.

Since you are using Azure B2C, that means we couldn't modify the token on the server.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Brando... yep I gave up trying and had to modify my system to accommodate for this